# How to deploy app to heroku with MongoDb/Mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am having trouble deploying my Node.JS app to Heroku, I know it's the database that is causing the issue but can't work out why. I am led to believe that I need to use Mlab instead of MongoDB Atlas so I have now tried both and neither work. When I deploy and visit the url I get an error. Here are the logs:

```
    2019-04-13T21:42:47.139176+00:00 app[web.1]:   operationTime:
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139180+00:00 app[web.1]:    Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1555191760 },
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139181+00:00 app[web.1]:   '$clusterTime':
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139182+00:00 app[web.1]:    { clusterTime:
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139183+00:00 app[web.1]:       Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1555191760 },
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139184+00:00 app[web.1]:      signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] } },
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139185+00:00 app[web.1]:   name: 'MongoError',
2019-04-13T21:42:47.139187+00:00 app[web.1]:   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
2019-04-13T21:42:47.880138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-13T21:43:19.726698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=my-personal-blog16.herokuapp.com request_id=fa43cfdb-4704-4b0d-8de0-5d65604dd98f fwd="92.233.88.145" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Here is my URI for connecting to the DB:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const dbpass = process.env.DB_PASS;
const mlabpass = process.env.MLAB_PASS;

module.exports = {
  MongoURI:
    `mongodb://fishj123:${mlabpass}@ds149885.mlab.com:49885/heroku_26921dvn`,

};
```

Link to my git repo: https://github.com/fishj123/personal-blog

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: are you passing the option { useNewUrlParser: true } into your mongoose connection? Check this link: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6664 Or maybe your password have special characters like @ ?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having similar issues - I worked out what was wrong. I hadn't set my Global Variables within Heroku, I hadn't realized that this was necessary.

Setting the variables in Heroku is as easy as going to the Settings tab and then setting the variables under Config Variables.